# Use argparse to parse a list of objects

Tags: python, terminal, argparse

I have a program with a function that takes a class initializer and list of objects. Each object consists of 3 variables id, value, and tag.

```
class Package():

    def __init__(self, id, value, name):
        if (value <= 0):
            raise ValueError("Amount must be greater than 0")
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
        self.tag = tag


 class Purchase():

    def submit(some_list):
        //Do stuff

def main():
    //Help here!
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("id", help="ID")
    parser.add_argument("value", help="Value")
    parser.add_argument("tag", help="Tag")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    some_list = [args.id, args.value, args.tag]
    submit(some_list)
```

I'm trying to implement argparse in main() so I can run the program by doing something like: `python foo.py "int0 [(int1, float1, int2), (int3, float2, int4) ....]"`.  The number of objects in the list is variable and depends on the user input.

```
initializer = num0

//First package object
package.id = num1
package.value = num2
package.tag = num3

//Second package object
package.id = num4
package.value = num5
package.tag = num6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a *custom [argument type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type)* and use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the value.

Working sample:

```
import argparse
from ast import literal_eval


class Package():
    def __init__(self, id, value, tag):
        if (value <= 0):
            raise ValueError("Amount must be greater than 0")
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
        self.tag = tag


def packages(s):
    try:
        data = literal_eval(s)
    except:  # TODO: avoid bare except and handle more specific errors
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Invalid 'packages' format.")

    return [Package(*item) for item in data]


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--packages', dest="packages", type=packages, nargs=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.packages)
```

Now if you would run the script, you would get a list of `Package` class instances printed:

```
$ python test.py --packages="[(1, 1.02, 3), (40, 2.32, 11)]"
[[<__main__.Package instance at 0x10a20d368>, <__main__.Package instance at 0x10a20d4d0>]]
```

Comment: Cool!  I've never used `ast.literal_eval()`.  When `return [Package(*item) for item in data]` is called, will all the arguments be stored in the right package variable (package.id, package.value, package.tag)?

Comment: @Brosef yup, these are `Package` instances in the list with all of the 3 fields initialized. Hope this is close to what you were looking for.

Comment: So do i leave my Package class initializer as it is?

Comment: should type = Packages? I get an unresolved reference warning when I use lower case packages

Comment: @Brosef just try running the code as is. Posted the complete code I execute locally.

Comment: My issue was I had packages() under the Package class.  Tried it again and this time it went through but I get a different error saying "error: argument --packages: invalid packages value: '[(1, 1.02, 3), (40, 2.32, 11)]'

Comment: @Brosef okay, I'm executing the script this way: `$ python test.py --packages="[(1, 1.02, 3), (40, 2.32, 11)]"` - works for me, tried with both 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: Got it!  So if I wanted to include that initializer that gets entered before the list would I add an extra parser argument like parser.add_argument('--initializer', dest="initializer", type=initializer, nargs=1)?

Comment: @Brosef for this `int0` value, I would use a separate simple argument with `type=int` or `type=float` and `nargs='?'`.

Comment: So is `dest` the parameter that refers to def packages()

Comment: @Brosef nope, `dest` is referring to the property you would get it from in the namespace later - `args.packages` in this case.

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought type referred to the actual argument type like float, int, etc.  It seems like it refers to the function that takes in the arguments.  If I change the name for def packages() the type=packages will get an error...

Comment: @Brosef from the docs: `type= can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value`. In our case `packages` function is a custom argument type.

Comment: I tried adding the initializer which does initialize the class, but when I get to packages I get the error saying 'invalid packages format'.  `python test.py --initializer="1"  --packages ="[(1, 1.00), (2, 2.00)]"`

Comment: @Brosef, yeah, cause the format is expected to be: a list where each item is a tuple with 3 items inside.

Comment: Sorry, I commented one of the items out, so the list is only expected to have two items now.  Also, doesn't look like the initializer is working when I combine them together.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to be a bit more explicit and use a custom action:

```
import argparse

class PackageAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PackageAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.nargs = 3

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        lst = getattr(namespace, self.dest, []) or []
        a, b, c = values
        lst.append(Package(int(a), float(b), int(c)))
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, lst)

class Package(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Package(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.foo, self.bar, self.baz)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--package', action=PackageAction)

print(parser.parse_args())
```

The usage here would look something like:

```
$ python packager.py --package 1 2 3 --package 4 5 6
Namespace(package=[Package(1, 2.0, 3), Package(4, 5.0, 6)])
```

One benefit is that you get slightly better default error handling ... e.g.:

```
$ python ~/sandbox/test.py --package 1 2 3 --package 4 5
usage: test.py [-h] [--package PACKAGE PACKAGE PACKAGE]
test.py: error: argument --package: expected 3 argument(s)
```

Of course, you can modify to suit your purposes -- specifically it would probably be good to provide a little extra [error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exiting-methods) to `__call__`.  e.g. you could do something like

```
parser.error('--package requires an int float and int')
```

if the user passed bad strings.  You could also provide better variable names :-)

Comment: Honestly, I like your answer better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my nomination; it uses a plain parser, and puts the customization in the `Package` class.

It would be called with something like:

```
python prog.py -p 0 1 2 --package 2 3 4
```

where `-p` or `--package` is followed by 3 values, and may be repeated (`action` is 'append').  `nargs=3` ensures that each `-p` is followed by 3 values (otherwise the parser raises an error).  Converting those values to numbers (and raising errors) is the responsibility of the `Package` class.  The class already has a check on non-negative `value`.

```
import argparse
class Package():
    def __init__(self, id, value, tag):
        # 3 inputs - numbers, but equivalent strings are accepted
        # may add more value validation
        self.id = int(id)
        self.value = float(value)
        if self.value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Amount must be greater than 0")
        self.tag = int(tag)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Package (%s, %s, %s)'%(self.id, self.value, self.tag)

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--package', nargs=3, action='append', default=[],
        metavar=('ID','Value','tag'), help='package parameters; may repeat')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    print args
    packages = [Package(*v) for v in args.package]
    return packages
    # alt
    # args.package = packages; return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.argv[1:]:
        print main(sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        # test cases
        print main([]) # nothing
        print main('-p 1 2 3'.split())
        print main('-p 0 1 2 --pack 2 3 4'.split())
        print main(['-h']) # help
```

A sample run of the test cases is:

```
2030:~/mypy$ python stack34823075.py 
Namespace(package=[])
[]
Namespace(package=[['1', '2', '3']])
[Package (1, 2.0, 3)]
Namespace(package=[['0', '1', '2'], ['2', '3', '4']])
[Package (0, 1.0, 2), Package (2, 3.0, 4)]

usage: stack34823075.py [-h] [-p ID Value tag]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p ID Value tag, --package ID Value tag
                        package parameters; may repeat
```

Note how the `metavar` affects the help display.  The `Package` `__repr__` method produces a nice list display.

---

Example of a run with non-numeric `tag`:

```
2038:~/mypy$ python stack34823075.py -p 1 2.3 tag
Namespace(package=[['1', '2.3', 'tag']])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack34823075.py", line 31, in <module>
    print main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "stack34823075.py", line 20, in main
    packages = [Package(*v) for v in args.package if v is not None]
  File "stack34823075.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.tag = int(tag)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tag'
```

A special `type` function does not work well here.  It would be applied to each of the 3 strings, individually, not as a group.

A custom `Action` class could handle the 3 values, converting each to `int`,`float`,`int`.  But even there I'd prefer to pass them to `Package`, e.g.

```
def __call__(self, namespace, dest, values):
    # store_action style
    new_value = Package(*values)
    setattr(namespace, dest, new_value) # store action
```

But since `packages = [Package(*v) for v in args.package]` is so simple, I don't see much point in customizing the parser or its actions.